# TypeScript: substitute existing type

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have a project that uses AngularJS and want to make a wrapper above the `$http` service. I want my request promises to have `abort()` method.

If I write

```
function request(params:ng.IRequestConfig):my.IRequestPromise {
  var promise = $http(params).then(onSuccess, onError);
  promise.abort = function () { // => here it fails with error "Property 'abort' does not exist on type 'IPromise<{}>'"
    ...
  }
  return promise;
}
```

it fails on the line with `abort` definition.

I have written an interface `IRequestPromise` which extends `ng.IPromise` by adding an `abort()` method. How can I make TypeScript consider `promise` as `my.IRequestPromise` but not `ng.IPromise`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cast the type (`ng.IPromise`) of promise returned to your type (`my.IRequestPromise` extended from `ng.IPromise`):

i.e

```
var promise = <my.IRequestPromise<yourreturntype>>$http(params).then(onSuccess, onError);
```

Assuming your extension is something like this:

```
export interface IRequestPromise<T> extends ng.IPromise<T> {
    ...
}
```

Also make sure your function return type is also property typed, i.e

```
function request(params:ng.IRequestConfig):my.IRequestPromise<anyOrSpecificTypeResolvedByPromise> {
```

Comment: Now it throws `type 'IRequestPromise' is not generic`. Seems like I don't understand something important about TypeScript...

Comment: You need to return `unction request(params:ng.IRequestConfig):my.IRequestPromise<youtypeOrAny> {` How does your interface def looks like `interface IRequestPromise extends ng.IPromise<{}>`?

Comment: my type is `IRequestPromise`. Do I need to pass it to itself? `my.IRequestPromise<my.IRequestPromise>`?

Comment: my interface def is `interface IRequestPromise<T> extends ng.IPromise<T>`

Comment: @Girafa `T` will the type of value returned by the promise, worst case example `any` or if you have a specific type ex: `User`. Your function return type should also have that Type i.e `function request(params:ng.IRequestConfig):my.IRequestPromise<any> {` for example. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you! Now it works, although I don't understand it all the same :)

Comment: @Girafa also remember you do not need to the type if your extension is `interface IRequestPromise extends ng.IPromise<any> {` but then it will become weakly typed and less generic..